# dmidecode type issue

Tags: linux, pci-express

I am trying to get PCIe linkspeed information by parsing dmidecode. When I run

```
sudo dmidecode -t 9
```

I get a handle that looks like this

```
Handle 0x001A, DMI type 9, 17 bytes System Slot Information
       Designation: PCIE1
       Type: x8 PCI Express 2 x16
       ...
```

What exactly is "Type: x8 PCI Express 2 x16" telling me? Is it saying that I have a x8 card plugged into a x16 slot? Been digging around for a few hours and can't find any answer. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `dmidecode` for this purpose just for learning purposes or fun? `lspci -vvv` provides you link speed information, bus width, latency information and plethora of other stuff.

Comment: It's for a utility I'm working on. About 10 minutes after I posted this I came upon lspci and was able to parse that output to get what I needed. Thank you very much for the suggestion

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to ServerFault! :)